# PHP - Failed to Open Stream Error (no such file or directory)

Tags: php

I have following directory structure for the project:

[image]

Home.php simply includes either of the two views i.e. login or invoice depending upon the session variables.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            include 'views/login.php';
        } else {
            include 'views/invoice.php';
        }
```

I include my constants file which contain database connection strings and other constants along with a autoloader file which register a autoload function to include all the classes.

```
include 'includes/constants.php';
include 'includes/autoloader.php';
```

It works without issues but when i use the same in get_data.php file it gives following error:

Warning: include(includes/constant.php): failed to open stream. No such file or directory.

Same error for autoloader.php too.

Comment: I already tried that but it's still the same error. I have tried following two: '../includes/constants.php' and './includes/constants.php'

Comment: Although highly unlikely on Win, will not hurt to check the permission. And have you tried absolute path?

Comment: I would try `../includes/constants.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)